# how to disable chrome alerts using nightwatch tests?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I need to disable the alert that pops up "Do you really want to leave the page?" in chrome when you try to move to another page quickly. How can I do that in nightwatch?

Comment: why do you need to disable it ? user-Pc will have that alert anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.acceptAlert()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/acceptAlert.html) command. It won't disable the prompt but it will actually handle it. This is the best resemblance of what the user will see and how they will handle it.